# How do I load a PHP class in a certain path?

Tags: php, class

I have a class, its located in `/some/path/Class.php` for example. Now I want to create an object of this class.

I tried that, but it did not work:

```
$obj = new some/path/Class();
```

I also tried to include the class be fore and to create the object the normal way, like this:

```
include('/some/path/Class.php');
$obj = new Class();
```

Throws an error, too. How can I create an object of that class?

Comment: the second way should work, maybe your path is not correct.

whats the exactly error message?

Comment: What error is thrown? And please show us the content of `/some/path/Class.php`

Comment: Can you be more specific, in what kind of error it throws?

Comment: Your include path must be wrong, read about [autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php)

Comment: just one recommendation, use namespaces. `composer` has a great implementation on namespace autoloading.

Comment: Where did you read about `new some/path/Class()`. That syntax does not exist. Were you thinking of namespaces? Whatever, it's sad that you got an error message (which is possibly telling you the exact problem) and decided to ignore it. Injecting random code until your script starts working is called [cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) and it's a very inefficient technique.

Comment: Would be helpful to know what error you get. Make sure the file is really included. Make sure the class name you initialize with `new Class()` matches the defined class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The include method you are using is correct, the problem seems to be the pathing to the file.

So you can either use relative pathing from the file you're calling it from:

```
include 'some/path/class.php';
```

Or use the full path:

```
include '/absolute/root/full/path/class.php';
```

To find out the full path, you could upload a simple PHP file with:

```
echo phpinfo();
```

then search on that page for 'SCRIPT_FILENAME' and that will show you the absolute path the current file is running from on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Use `dirname(__FILE__) . '/some/path/Class.php'`

where `dirname(__FILE__)` is the path of the file calling this class.

Answer (score 0):

```
include('/some/path/Class.php');
```

This will start looking in the root folder, so you would have to supply the full path to the file which obviously doesn't make sense.

Use something like

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

to use a relative path. You might also want to declare a constant in your index.php (or in another file that gets autoloaded) that contains the base path of your application and then use that instead.